# Bootstrap modal moves down the page when resizing the page for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that pop-up on my page on click. It is perfectly centered in a browser view and smaller views. In the moment I make the page small as for phones the modal goes down the page and I have to scroll to see it. How can I fix this?

```
.nx-modal {
position: absolute;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 15px;
z-index: 1050;
width: 96%;
```

}

```
<div class="page-container">
<div class="container">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- ko if: currentDialog() !== null -->
            <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
            <div id="Modal" class="nx-modal" data-bind="dsfsdfsdf"}" style="display: none;">
                @* This is where dialog's content is loaded *@
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are there any other styles assigned to the modal that are overriding ? Like Media queries for instance ?You could try adding media queries for smaller screen and give your modal a `top:0px` and `left:0px` it might help in this case..

Try this

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
 .modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  width: 96%;
  }
}
```